# Problems on complex questions

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, online-resources

I'm a senior in my high school studying complex numbers. I have a test coming up in a few days. I want to explore more questions outside my textbook and school questions. Can someone suggest a few resources where I can get good questions of complex numbers from?

The type of questions I want to practice are not very advanced complex numbers(no calculus, matrices, functions, etc).

Below is one question which I considered the most "advanced/hardest" among the questions I have.

> \begin{array}{l}{\text { By considering } \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+i \tan \theta)^{k}, \text { show that }} \\ {\qquad \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos k \theta \sec ^{k} \theta=\cot \theta \sin n \theta \sec ^{n} \theta} \\ {\text { provided } \theta \text { is not an integer multiple of } \frac{1}{2} \pi .}\end{array}

Comment: Don't you have any more problems, right now? Please put single problem with sufficient effort on that

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Please don't misunderstand me. I am not asking the community to solve the problems I displayed. These are just examples of the problems I have. I need problems similar to these. I don't need answers to these problems. That is why this question is tagged as a resource request.

Comment: I've removed the 2 questions now.

Comment: I’m sorry your question is being misunderstood, I know it is extremely frustrating. If you have access to a college library, you could try looking at chapter 1 of various books on complex analysis; some have a few problems like that.

Comment: @NoLand'sMan, See https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs  and https://archive.org/details/planetrigonometr01lone/page/n8

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to find questions involving complex numbers that do not also involve the topics that you wish to avoid (i.e. calculus, matrices, functions).  Similar to what others have suggested, find a book on complex analysis and confine yourself to the book's chapter 1.

I can suggest three specific problems that you might tackle, assuming that you are familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula:

(1) Using the quadratic equation, derive the 3 roots of 
$0 = (z^3 - 1) = (z - 1)(z^2 + z + 1).$ 
Then compare the results with $[(\cos 2k\pi/3) + i(\sin 2k\pi/3),\;$ where $\;k = 0, 1, \;\text{or}\; 2.$  
Considering (for example) $\;\cos (2\pi/3),\;$ which is closely related to the special angle $\;\cos (\pi/3),\;$ you should observe that geometric analysis (+ DeMoivre's theorem) yield the identical results as the 3 roots of the corresponding cubic equation.

(2) Prove to yourself that $\;(\cos \alpha + i\,\sin \alpha)(\cos \,\beta + i\,\sin \beta) = \cos \,[\alpha + \beta] + i\,\sin [\alpha + \beta].$

(3) A slightly harder problem than #1 above: use complex analysis to derive the $\;\cos 2\pi/5\;$ as follows:

Let $\;z_1 = [(\cos 2\pi/5) + i(\sin 2\pi/5)] \Rightarrow$ 
$z_1\;$ is a root of $\;0 = (z^5 - 1) = (z - 1)(z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1).$
**Conjecture** that $\;(z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1)\;$ can be factored into $\;(z^2 +az + 1)(z^2 + bz + 1)\;$
and see what constraints this places on $a$ and $b$.
Use the quadratic equation to determine values for $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the constraints.
Having done this, you should be able to conclude that $z_1$ is one of the following 4 roots:
$(1/2) [-a \pm (\text{some stuff})] \;\text{or}\; (1/2) [-b \pm (\text{some stuff})].$ 
Since the imaginary part of $z_1$ equals $(\sin 2\pi/5),$ which is not equal to zero, 
for whichever one of the 4 roots pertains to $z_1$, the *some stuff* portion **must represent a non-zero imaginary number.**
Therefore, **the real portion of** $z_1$ is **either** $(1/2)(-a)\;$ or $\;(1/2)(-b).$ 
Since $\;0 < cos (2\pi/5) = \;$ the **real portion of** $z_1,$

all you have to do is determine which of $(1/2)(-a)\;$ or $\;(1/2)(-b)$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+i\tan \theta)^{k}=\frac {1- (1+i\tan \theta)^{n}} {1- (1+i\tan \theta)}$ from the formula for a geometric sum. Now $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+i\tan \theta)^{k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (e^{i\theta})^{k}\sec^{k} (\theta)$. So the required result can b derived by taking real parts in the equation $\frac {1- (1+i\tan \theta)^{n}} {1- (1+i\tan \theta)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ik\theta}\sec^{k} (\theta)$.

I will let you try the other two questions yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do you have any idea where I can find similar problems? I am more interested in tackling similar problems, than finding the answer to the problem above.

Comment: One thing you can do is to get hold of a book on Fourier series and look at the  formulas involving Dirichlet and Fejer kernels. Try to derive these formulas on your own. @NoLand'sMan

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems similar to the one you quoted in Chapter 1 of *Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Complex Variables With an Introduction to Conformal Mapping and Its Applications* by Murray R. Spiegel.

Chapter 1 is a short chapter, only 32 pages of a 313-page book, so it may not seem worthwhile to buy the book for just one chapter, but on the other hand, the book is very reasonably priced for a math book, and it also contains a lot of good information if you eventually go beyond the first chapter.  The emphasis of the book is on applications, not theory.